# Flutter Web crashes with Cannot open file client.js

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

May I ask your help about this error 
It's happen when I'm trying for the first time running my flutter web which using flutter run -d chrome

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Syncing files to device Chrome...                                       
25,220ms (!)
GET /dwds/src/injected/client.js
Error thrown by handler.
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\Acer\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\dwds-2.0.1\lib\src\injected\client.js' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
dart:isolate  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

And if I trying run using

```
flutter run -d web
```

It's doesn't thrown any error but on the website it goes blank white nothing shown up.
Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

adding the following in the pubspec.yaml worked for me. I am using beta channel.

```
dependencies:
dwds: ^16.0.1
```

then run command:

```
flutter update-packages
```

Comment: I put you a plus and at the same time thought about it. Is it really impossible to do everything so that there are no such problems?

Comment: I am also hoping for that. But,  whenever there are some changes, we always encounter such kind of problems

Comment: Thanks, you might want to get the latest compatible version of dwds from https://pub.dev/packages/dwds

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I don't know the exact root cause of the problem but I have a hack to make it work.

I was facing the issue after I deleted `.pub-cache` folder, so from my recycler bin I picked `dwds-2.0.1` folder and reverted back. This hack working

Answer (score 0):

add `dwds` package in your dependencies and run `flutter update-packages`. It will work :)