# Flutter Web: Unhandled error detected in the injected client.js script on flutter run

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am getting the following errors when I run `flutter run -d chrome`. I am unable to figure out where this error is coming from. I tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768325/flutter-web-crashes-with-cannot-open-file-client-js) but did not change anything.

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
> Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.20.2, on Linux, locale en_CA.UTF-8)   [✓]
> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
> 30.0.0) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 4.0) [✓] Connected device (4 available)

Could you please help ?

```
client.js:3316 Unhandled error detected in the injected client.js script.

You can disable this script in webdev by passing --no-injected-client if it
is preventing your app from loading, but note that this will also prevent
all debugging and hot reload/restart functionality from working.

The original error is below, please file an issue at
https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/new and attach this output:

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get$digestsPath' (J.getInterceptor$x(...).get$digestsPath is not a function)
TypeError: J.getInterceptor$x(...).get$digestsPath is not a function
    at Object.get$digestsPath$x (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3529:43)
    at http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22757:60
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3824:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11021:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3788:20)
    at RequireRestarter._getDigests$0 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22769:16)
    at http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22784:48
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3824:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11021:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3788:20)
    at RequireRestarter._initialize$0 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22792:16)
    at http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8594:45
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3824:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11021:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3788:20)
    at Object.RequireRestarter_create (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8606:16)
    at http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22344:38
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3824:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11021:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11007:32)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4152:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12326:39)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11387:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3936:93)
    at _Future._complete$1 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11211:11)
    at Object._cancelAndValue (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4091:16)
    at Stream_first_closure0.call$1 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11479:9)
    at _EventStreamSubscription_onData_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:17334:30)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4158:16)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12326:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12258:14)
    at _CustomZone_bindUnaryCallbackGuarded_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12461:25)
    at invokeClosure (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1205:26)
    at EventSource.<anonymous> (http://localhost:35691/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1224:18)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that a Chrome change caused the issue that's been resolved by a change in the Dart SDK.

A `flutter upgrade` will get you the latest Dark SDK that will resolve this error.

[More information](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/1133) on the [SDK update](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/34b485c0c4ef3a1b24f89fb2af3ec6ec6837a401) on Github

Comment: I was having the same problem and after upgrading flutter the error went away. Flutter version when I was having the error (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows) my current version is Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows.